# Access: Multiple columns pulling from one key

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm very new to this and I don't know anything about code. I've watched some tutorials so I know the most bare minimum basics, and I can't find any bare minimum solutions to this.

I have two tables: Faculty and Active Awards. Faculty key is FacultyID. Active Awards key is AwardID.

Every Award record has at least one faculty attached to it. Easy stuff, created a relationship and now on the Faculty table you can see what Awards are connected to them if they're the first person listed on the award paperwork. My issue is, some of these awards (which include research grants) have more than one faculty person attached, up to 4 additional people ("Co-PIs"). Those additional people can't get connected to their awards. I tried adding additional Faculty boxes in the Relationship screen, and linking each of those to the different Co-PIs, but it doesn't seem to work.

The final result should be that when you look at the Faculty table and click the little + symbol next to the person's name, you can see every award attached to that person. This will also eventually show every patent attached to that person, which will be from a new Patents table but will also include multiple people per record. So if Sally Smith was part of a team that got two grants last year and also invented something that we patented, it should show all of that.

Sorry if I'm explaining this wrong. I couldn't find the right keywords for Google to give me an answer so I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation when dealing with databases.
There are People who can receive multiple awards and awards that can be assigned to multiple people.

People (many) to (many) Awards results in a many-to-many join
You will need a third table to hold the joins as follows:

```
[People]{ PK[Id], [Name], ... }
[Award]{ PK[Id], [Award], [Description], ... }
[M2MAward]{ PK[fkPeopleId], PK[fkAwardId] }

One-to-Many [People].[Id] > [M2MAward].[fkPeopleId]
One-to-Many [Award].[Id] > [M2MAward].[fkAwardId]
```

The link below has a step-by-step approach to building the joins you will need.
[MS Access - Many-To-Many Relationship](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_many_to_many_relationships.htm)